# How to show the date time differences from two different columns

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have events table having two column 
evt_date_time_from datatype as datetime,
evt_date_time_to datatype as datetime.
I want to check whether the date selected is same or different and to show the amount of time for that particular event.
If same date and time is selected then it should show **Thu, 2017-06-22, 10:30 AM - 03:00 PM**
else it should show **Thu, 2017-06-22 to 2017-06-25, 10:30 AM - 03:00 PM**

Comment: For Date Difference Try [date_diff](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm unable to post a comment (I need atleast 50 reputation), I'll post an answer. I would just convert the value to timestamps using `strtotime()`.

You can then compare the 2 values inside a condition of an if/else statement.

An example:

```
$timeOne = strtotime("Thu, 2017-06-22, 10:30 AM");
$timeTwo = strtotime("Thu, 2017-06-22, 03:00 PM");

if($timeOne == $timeTwo){
    /* Do something when the two times are the same */
} else {
    /* Do something when they're not the same */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $DateOne = strtotime($event->evt_date_time_from_dt);
    $DateTwo = strtotime($event->evt_date_time_to_dt);

    $timeOne = $event->evt_time_from;
    $timeTwo = $event->evt_time_to;
    $event_date='';
    $evt_date='';
    if($DateOne == $DateTwo){
      /* Do something when the two times are the same */
      if ($timeOne != $timeTwo) {
      $event_date = $event->evt_date_time_from_dt.','.$timeOne.'-'.$timeTwo;
      }   
    } else {
        /* Do something when they're not the same */
        $event_date_to ='To: '.$event->evt_date_time_to_dt.','.$timeTwo;
        $event_date = 'From: '.$event->evt_date_time_from_dt.','.$timeOne.'<br>'.$event_date_to;

    }
?>   
Then I print it this way--
 <?php echo $event_date;?>
```